# Python .sort "None" error

Tags: python, sorting

I am a python beginner and am simply trying to make a small piece of code that will alphabetically sort names and print them out in order on new lines.

This is my code:

```
names=input("Students: ")
newlist=names.split(" ")
alpha=newlist.sort()
for i in alpha:
    print(i)
```

I am using python 3.6.0 and when I attempt to run the code and enter names, the code returns "None". Any tips on how to make my code neater, and ideas on where i might be going wrong?

Comment: `newlist.sort()` returns `None`, because it sorts in place. Use `sorted(newlist)` if you want to create a sorted copy instead. See the duplicate.

Comment: instead of using `alpha=newlist.sort()` use `newlist.sort(); alpha = newlist` and then go ahead with your for loop. The `.sort()` method doesn't return anything, it simply modifies the list its called on. To assign the sorted list to a new variable, first sort the list and then assign